# django.core.servers.basehttp.FileWrapper disappears in Django 1.9

Tags: python, django, django-upgrade

I am migrating from django 1.8 to 1.9. and I got the following error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'FileWrapper'

I import it as follow:

```
from django.core.servers.basehttp import FileWrapper
```

Searching this name in django 1.9 release notes gives no result. What is the replacement for `FileWrapper` ?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Django just had a wrapper to the wsgiref module you can just get it directly

```
from wsgiref.util import FileWrapper
```