# crash when trying to download pdf file

Tags: python, django

It was working on django 1.8, and python 2.7
When I upgraded libraries and app to django 2.2 and python 3.6.8
I am getting the error below. Which is in libraries, rather than my code
its worth to note, i changed an import from django.core.servers.basehttp import FileWrappter to wsgiref.util import FileWrapper

```
[08/Jan/2020 16:46:33] "GET /policy/download/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 179, in finish_response
    for data in self.result:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/util.py", line 30, in __next__
    data = self.filelike.read(self.blksize)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 11: invalid start byte
[08/Jan/2020 16:46:33] "GET /policy/download/ HTTP/1.1" 500 59
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 33210)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 179, in finish_response
    for data in self.result:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/util.py", line 30, in __next__
    data = self.filelike.read(self.blksize)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 11: invalid start byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 141, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "/home/bsd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 116, in handle_error
    super().handle_error()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 654, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 364, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 724, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/home/bsd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 169, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/home/bsd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 194, in handle_one_request
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()
  File "/home/bsd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 111, in close
    super().close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
----------------------------------------
Policy matching query does not exist.
[08/Jan/2020 16:46:33] "GET /policy/download/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 179, in finish_response
    for data in self.result:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/util.py", line 30, in __next__
    data = self.filelike.read(self.blksize)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 11: invalid start byte
[08/Jan/2020 16:46:33] "GET /policy/download/ HTTP/1.1" 500 59
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 33214)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 179, in finish_response
    for data in self.result:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/util.py", line 30, in __next__
    data = self.filelike.read(self.blksize)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 11: invalid start byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 141, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "/home/bsd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 116, in handle_error
    super().handle_error()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 654, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 364, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 724, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/home/bsd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 169, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/home/bsd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 194, in handle_one_request
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()
  File "/home/bsd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 111, in close
    super().close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
----------------------------------------
Policy matching query does not exist.
[08/Jan/2020 16:46:33] "GET /policy/download/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 179, in finish_response
    for data in self.result:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/util.py", line 30, in __next__
    data = self.filelike.read(self.blksize)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 11: invalid start byte
[08/Jan/2020 16:46:33] "GET /policy/download/ HTTP/1.1" 500 59
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 33218)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 179, in finish_response
    for data in self.result:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/util.py", line 30, in __next__
    data = self.filelike.read(self.blksize)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 11: invalid start byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 141, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "/home/bsd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 116, in handle_error
    super().handle_error()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 654, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 364, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 724, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/home/bsd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 169, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/home/bsd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 194, in handle_one_request
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()
  File "/home/bsd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 111, in close
    super().close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
----------------------------------------
Policy matching query does not exist.
[08/Jan/2020 16:46:33] "GET /policy/download/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 179, in finish_response
    for data in self.result:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/util.py", line 30, in __next__
    data = self.filelike.read(self.blksize)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 11: invalid start byte
[08/Jan/2020 16:46:33] "GET /policy/download/ HTTP/1.1" 500 59
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 33222)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 179, in finish_response
    for data in self.result:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/util.py", line 30, in __next__
    data = self.filelike.read(self.blksize)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 11: invalid start byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 141, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "/home/bsd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 116, in handle_error
    super().handle_error()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 654, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 364, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 724, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/home/bsd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 169, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/home/bsd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 194, in handle_one_request
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()
  File "/home/bsd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 111, in close
    super().close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
----------------------------------------
Policy matching query does not exist.
[08/Jan/2020 16:46:33] "GET /policy/download/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 179, in finish_response
    for data in self.result:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/util.py", line 30, in __next__
    data = self.filelike.read(self.blksize)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 11: invalid start byte
[08/Jan/2020 16:46:33] "GET /policy/download/ HTTP/1.1" 500 59
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 33226)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 179, in finish_response
    for data in self.result:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/util.py", line 30, in __next__
    data = self.filelike.read(self.blksize)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 11: invalid start byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 141, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "/home/bsd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 116, in handle_error
    super().handle_error()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 654, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 364, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 724, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/home/bsd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 169, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/home/bsd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 194, in handle_one_request
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()
  File "/home/bsd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 111, in close
    super().close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
----------------------------------------
Policy matching query does not exist.
[08/Jan/2020 16:46:33] "GET /policy/download/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 179, in finish_response
    for data in self.result:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/util.py", line 30, in __next__
    data = self.filelike.read(self.blksize)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 11: invalid start byte
[08/Jan/2020 16:46:33] "GET /policy/download/ HTTP/1.1" 500 59
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 33230)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 179, in finish_response
    for data in self.result:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/util.py", line 30, in __next__
    data = self.filelike.read(self.blksize)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 11: invalid start byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 141, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "/home/bsd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 116, in handle_error
    super().handle_error()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 654, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 364, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 724, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/home/bsd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 169, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/home/bsd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 194, in handle_one_request
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()
  File "/home/bsd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 111, in close
    super().close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
----------------------------------------
Policy matching query does not exist.
[08/Jan/2020 16:46:33] "GET /policy/download/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 179, in finish_response
    for data in self.result:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/util.py", line 30, in __next__
    data = self.filelike.read(self.blksize)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 11: invalid start byte
[08/Jan/2020 16:46:33] "GET /policy/download/ HTTP/1.1" 500 59
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 33234)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 179, in finish_response
    for data in self.result:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/util.py", line 30, in __next__
    data = self.filelike.read(self.blksize)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 11: invalid start byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 141, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "/home/bsd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 116, in handle_error
    super().handle_error()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 654, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 364, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 724, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/home/bsd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 169, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/home/bsd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 194, in handle_one_request
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()
  File "/home/bsd/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 111, in close
    super().close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
----------------------------------------
Policy matching query does not exist.
[08/Jan/2020 16:46:33] "GET /policy/download/ HTTP/1.1" 200 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 179, in finish_response
    for data in self.result:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/util.py", line 30, in __next__
    data = self.filelike.read(self.blksize)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 11: invalid start byte
[08/Jan/2020 16:46:33] "GET /policy/download/ HTTP/1.1" 500 59
----------------------------------------
```

the views part

```
def download_policy(request):
    the_file = None
    try:
        policy = Policy.objects.get(name="BSD_POLICY")
        the_file = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, str(policy.policy))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        the_file = "base/document-not-found.pdf"

    filename = os.path.basename(the_file)
    chunk_size = 8192
    response = StreamingHttpResponse(FileWrapper(open(the_file), chunk_size),
                                content_type=mimetypes.guess_type(the_file)[0])
    response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(the_file)    
    response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % filename
    log(
        user=request.user, action="FILE_DOWNLOAD_REQUEST", extra={ "file_path":the_file, "file_length":response['Content-Length'] }
    )
    return response



class Policy(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15, default="BSD_POLICY")
    policy = models.FileField(upload_to="policy/")
```

Comment: In general, try to avoid upgrading Python and Django at the same time. It makes it trickier to narrow down NoneType' object is not subscriptablewhat caused the problem. It might be a good idea to upgrade via Django 1.11 LTS as well. If you want help with the specific problem, then show the view for the `/policy/download/` URL.

Comment: posted it......

Comment: Try opening the file as bytes, e.g. `open(the_file, 'rb')`. You might be able to simplify the code by using [`FileResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#fileresponse-objects).

Comment: Can you also paste the `Policy` model? Is `policy.policy` a `FileField`?

Comment: posted that one too.

Comment: its worth to note, i changed an import from django.core.servers.basehttp import FileWrappter to wsgiref.util import FileWrapper

Comment: As an aside, `except Exception as e` is bad practice. What do you mean by _i changed an import from django.core.servers.basehttp import FileWrappter to wsgiref.util import FileWrapper_?

Comment: in django 1.8 FileWrapper used to be in django.core.servers.basehttp, but now moved to wsgiref.util  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35817597/django-core-servers-basehttp-filewrapper-disappears-in-django-1-9